# createBottomTabNavigator with dynamic tabStyle for different tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

According to the [Document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#bottomtabnavigatorconfig), I can change `activeTintColor` and `activeBackgroundColor` in `tabBarOptions`.

Is there a way to style the tab button with something like `activeTabBarStyle`?

I want to add a `borderTop` to the active tab, like this:

[image: figma]

So I created a function for the `defaultNavigationOptions` to dynamically assign the `tabStyle` for different tabs:

```
// ...
const BottomNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Users: {
        screen: UsersStackNavigator,
    },
    Dashboard: {
        screen: DashboardStackNavigator,
    },
    Coupons: {
        screen: CouponsStackNavigator,
    }
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        // ...
        const active = navigation.isFocused();
        const width = active ? 2 : 0;  // This outputs 3 times, which are 2, 0, 0
        return {
            // ...
            tabBarOptions: {
                // ...
                tabStyle: {
                    paddingTop: 10,
                    borderTopColor: '#3A3AB5',
                    borderTopWidth: width
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

The `width` seems working but all the three tabs are only using the activated `navigationOptions`:

I don't know why the color can be different why not other styles as well?

[image]

Any ideas how to work around with it?

Comment: I think this question is about [`react-navigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/) and not [`react-native-navigation`](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) as the tag used.

Comment: you might want to refer to [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/504#issuecomment-308560620)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve a specific tab styling behaviour in a demo project,  here's the essential part of it,

First of all, i created a customBottomBar using `react-navigation-tabs bottomTabBar`, this is the component i used:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs'
import { View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
var { height } = Dimensions.get("window")

const TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper = ({
    onPress,
    onLongPress,
    testID,
    accessibilityLabel,
    ...props
}) => {
    if (props.focused) props.style.push(styles.tabBarStyle)
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            testID={testID}
            hitSlop={{
                left: 15,
                right: 15,
                top: 5,
                bottom: 5,
            }}
            accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
        >
            <View {...props} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}

export default TabBarComponent = props => {
    return <BottomTabBar
        {...props}
        style={styles.bottomBarStyle}
        getButtonComponent={() => {
            return TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper
        }}
    />
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bottomBarStyle: {
        //if you need to style the whole bottom bar
    },
    tabBarStyle: {
        borderTopWidth: 1
    }
})
```

What i did here is that i exported as-is the BottomTabBar provided by react-navigation, so it kept the same style i defined on the `createBottomTabNavigator` level.

After that, i used the `getButtonComponent` props, that lets me return a custom component for every button. For every button, react-navigation already passes the informations we need to render the button with the specific infos.

One of those informations is `focused` that let's me know which tab is getting rendered in a specific time.

Another `info` we get is the default style table `react-navigation` uses to renders his button which is an array, that's why i'm pushing it inside `props.style`

In the example I'm creating the button with the `borderWidth: 1` style, but you can style it further based off your needs, i've left also a style you can use to style the bottomTabBar.

Created the `customBottomBar` you just need to import it where you defined you `createBottomTabNavigator` and pass it using `tabBarComponent`.

```
import BottomBar from "path/to/BottomBar"

createBottomTabNavigator({
   myScreen:{
      screen:myScreen
   }
   },{
   initialRouteName:"routeName",
   tabBarComponent: (props) => <BottomBar {...props} />
})
```

Let me know if i missed something or need explanation of something specific

Comment: Works great! And I modified it a little bit so I can style both active and inactive tab buttons. Thanks very much!