# React-Native how do you add a border to a single tab of the bottom navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am currently facing a styling issue with my bottom navigation in React-Native.

**Current bottom navigation**

Currently, I am creating bottom navigation with the following code.

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'home',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
                <Image
// Icon with styling here
                />
            )
        },
    },

    Settings: {
        screen: Settings,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'settings',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
                <Image
// Icon with styling here
                />
            )
        },
    },
}, {
    tabBarOptions: {
// Styling here
    }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

This works fine.

**Desired end situation**

I am trying to implement a small light-blue gap between the tabs.

This would look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBRXW.jpg

Does someone know if this is even possible with React Navigation / has a solution?

Comment: I've responded to a similar issue, try checking if it works for you. You can check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279747/createbottomtabnavigator-with-dynamic-tabstyle-for-different-tabs/58377910#58377910

Comment: Thanks @Auticcat for your comment. I managed to get it kinda working. I applied styling to tabStyle which gives styling to every tab. However now it also gives a light-blue border at the right side of the last element. It should only do the border between elements not at the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Following the example i posted in the comments, to add the actual borderWidth I imagine that, inside the `TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper` function, you did something like:

```
const TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper = ({
    onPress,
    onLongPress,
    testID,
    accessibilityLabel,
    ...props
}) => {
    props.style.push({borderRightWidth:1})
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            testID={testID}
            hitSlop={{
                left: 15,
                right: 15,
                top: 5,
                bottom: 5,
            }}
            accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
        >
            <View {...props} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
```

This will add a border between each button, but will also add a border at the last button you have.

To work around that you need to change the way you render the button in your `getButtonComponent` props (passed at the bottomBar).

This props is a buttonComponent that passes as parameter the current button `route`.

So you can do:

```
<BottomTabBar
   ...
   getButtonComponent={ ({route}) => {
      if(route.name === "Settings") return TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapperWithoutBorder
      else return TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper
      } 
   }
```

Then the `TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapperWithoutBorder` would be the normal button:

```
const TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper = ({
    onPress,
    onLongPress,
    testID,
    accessibilityLabel,
    ...props
}) => {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            testID={testID}
            hitSlop={{
                left: 15,
                right: 15,
                top: 5,
                bottom: 5,
            }}
            accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
        >
            <View {...props} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
```

Let me know if there's something unclear